# How can create credential authentication in Next.js with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, next-auth

I have a website which I want to add credential authentication. But there is no enough documentation or youtube video to get much information about Next.js and postgresql credential login implementation. Next-auth library documentation is so poor, and complicated. I don't want to use vercel, supabase or etc, I will use my own VPS for deployment.

How can I get much information about PostgreSQL and Next.js credential auth integration ?